# Display a table of data in JSP from Servlet

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, netbeans, attributes

If there are lots of data rows, how can I show it on my JSP page with the attribute of course, name, admno as a row by row?

```
String sql = "Select * FROM details WHERE ADMNO = '" + adm + "'";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
  String course = rs.getString("COURSE");
  String name = rs.getString("NAME");
  String admno = rs.getString("ADMNO");

  request.setAttribute("course", course);
  request.setAttribute("name", name);
  request.setAttribute("admno", admno);

  System.err.println(course + " " + name + " " + admno);

  d = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/output.jsp");
  d.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Your code will have issues. you shouldnt put request dispatcher in while loop. OMG:( . when the first time it gets executed, the control will goes to the jsp page and the next record will not be processed.

Comment: Also, after editing the indentation of your code, I feel like you're missing the closing `}` on your while loop, or you didn't include all of the code.

Comment: haven't include all my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Your code will have issues. you shouldn't put request dispatcher in while loop. OMG:( . when the first time it gets executed, the control will goes to the jsp page and the the loop will not be executed again, as the control goes out of hand to a JSP.

I can suggest you 3 steps

1.Create a bean like

```
 Class Student{
         String course;
         String name;
         String admNo;
         //Add getters and setters for all the members.
         //May be you can use constructor also for initializing in single shot.
    }
```

2.Create a list of Student in your Servlet.Create student object for each record in the ResultSet.Add this student to student list.place student list in the request.

3.Use [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) and iterate over the student list and display in your JSP

```
<c:forEach var="student" items="${studentlist}"> 
.... Your code here ...
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Hmm i  didn't know so much of it, but currently I've tried using <td>${course}</td> to display on my JSP. Only one record appear which isn't what i wanted when there are four records.So is there anyway i can edit from there instead?

Comment: Seems your records are overwritted. in your request there will be only one course ,one name and one admno. so i am suggesting you to create a Bean and add the bean in a list and sent in the request. so that you will have all the data in the resultset in your request

Comment: @Yong. first Change the while loop.put the requestdispatcher out of the while loop

Comment: @Yong: You can accept this answer, if you found it works

Comment: if i were to do a statistical summary  of name from

<c:forEach var="student" items="${studentlist}"> 
${student.name}
</c:forEach>

is this possible?